# How to exclude localhost from htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost

I use the following directive in my .htaccess in order to execute our scripts with PHP 7 :

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-7
</FilesMatch>
```

It works fine on my production server, but not in localhost. So my question is: **how can I exclude localhost from the FilesMatch directive?**

I have tried many things. "Directory" and "DirectoryMatch" can't be used in .htaccess. "If" can be used in .htaccess but for some reason, the following does not work :

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'localhost'">
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-7
    </FilesMatch>
</If>
```

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: Apache version 2.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out it works when reversing the "FilesMatch" and "If" tags:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'localhost'">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-7
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

I don't know why, but it works.